# Middle alternation with stative verbs

Tags: meaning, middle-voice

Is there any semantic difference between the following sentences?

1. I frighten easily.
2. I'm easily frightened.

Do they mean the same? Or sentence 1 means that I cause myself to be frightened and sentence 2 means that there must be something or somebody that frightens me easily?

Does the interpretation of the above sentences change if we add adjuncts?

3. I frighten easily for Tom.
4. I'm easily frightened by Tom.

Comment: Sentence (3) is not idiomatic. You can't frighten _for_ someone.#

Comment: @KateBunting Agreed. It is mere pedantry to think that Tom might want you to go around frightening people on his behalf. I therefore ignored this secondary question.

Comment: 1 and 2 mean virtually the same thing, but 2 uses the passive voice (as does 4). 3 could only be imagined grammatical with some odd backstory for context. cf. *The spoon bends easily for Uri Geller but not for me*...

Answer (score 2):

It may help to clarify meaning, For example:

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/frighten)
*frighten*  TRANSITIVE VERB

1. to make afraid or fearful; throw into a fright; terrify; scare
2. (usually fol. by away, off, etc)
   *to drive by scaring*
   *to frighten away pigeons from the roof*
   *frighten* INTRANSITIVE VERB
3. to become frightened
   *a timid child who frightens easily*

So "I frighten easily" may mean that you have the capacity to scare others; perhaps you have a menacing appearance or an frightening sound to your voice.

It also has the second meaning (which you probably thought of in asking your question) that it does not take much to frighten you; a bump in the night, a weird face, a little threat - small things, whereas one who does not frighten easily would scarcely notice or care. In this case it describes your nature, character, perhaps your behaviour. It is essentially a description of *you*.

"I am easily Frightened" puts a little more emphasis on the subject that does the frightening; it implies that there are things that frighten you and that they need not be great to put you in a scared state.

But despite this argument, the differences are slight.

Comment: Generic usages imply either repeated or permanent experience, especially with mental predicates. And the middle alternation is limited to transitive verbs (causative/inchoative verbs like _frighten_ are limited to causative senses in the middle, according to Levin).